# Swift UI stacked bordered views consistent border thickness

Tags: swift, swiftui, border

In my Swift UI project, I have a number of vertically stacked views each with a black border. See this example visual:

[image]

Note that the top and bottom borders merge together to form a sort of thicker border. How do I make the merged top / bottom borders look the same thickness as the horizontal borders? In CSS I would simply make the thickness of the top and bottom borders half of the horizontal borders, but Swift doesn't have the capability of changing border widths for each edge as far as I know.

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                    Text("Example \(i)")
                        .font(.title)
                        .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                        .id(i)
                        .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    value.scrollTo(99)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On each edge, you can just overlay a `Rectangle`. The rectangles on the top and bottom are half the height, so when together, it is the same size as the width ones.

Code:

```
ScrollView {
    ScrollViewReader { value in
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                Text("Example \(i)")
                    .font(.title)
                    .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                    .id(i)
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle().frame(height: 2),
                        alignment: .top
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle().frame(height: 2),
                        alignment: .bottom
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle().frame(width: 4),
                        alignment: .leading
                    )
                    .overlay(
                        Rectangle().frame(width: 4),
                        alignment: .trailing
                    )
            }
        }
        .onAppear() {
            value.scrollTo(99)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The other thing I just thought of was using an offset to shift each box upwards so the top / bottom borders overlap. I'll try this too, though.

Comment: @JohnSorensen Problem with that is the first or last box will be uneven.

Answer (score 1):

A little bit of a hacky solution but managed to have the result with a negative spacing in a VStack wrapping the view

```
struct test: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                VStack(spacing: -4){
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text("Example \(i)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            .id(i)
                            .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                    }
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    value.scrollTo(99)

                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: result of the code]

Comment: Honestly that's probably the most elegant solution I've seen yet...

Comment: Got to agree, didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way would be to add a negative `padding`. Just make the padding value half of the border width. Some other notes:

- Make sure to add a `VStack` or [`LazyVStack`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/lazyvstack) inside your `ScrollView` - otherwise, you won't be able to have fine control over spacing, alignment, or layout.
- I recommend `LazyVStack` because you have 100 `Text`s, which is a lot. When you have lots of elements such as `Text`, use `LazyVStack` to improve performance.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            ScrollViewReader { value in
                LazyVStack(spacing: 0) { /// better performance + set spacing to 0
                    ForEach(0..<100) { i in
                        Text("Example \(i)")
                            .font(.title)
                            .frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                            .id(i)
                            .border(Color.black, width: 4)
                            .padding(.vertical, -2) /// make this half of the border width
                    }
                }
                .onAppear() {
                    value.scrollTo(99)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]